# Retrieving fields in the url using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html

I try to retrieve the following fields: `UID_TARGET`(From All subscribers), `LAST_VISIT_DATE` (From Data Extension), `LAST_STATION_TYPE` (From Data Extension) in the URL after clicking on the button submit.
When I add the AMPScript code at the page level (text) display a error message.
and, when I use the code amp script at the button, it does not retrieve the data.

**AMPScript Code :**

```
%%[
var @last_visite_date, @UID, @last_station_type
 SET @UID = [UID_TARGET] 
 SET @last_visite_date = Lookup("ENT.ACTIVITY_LOT_6","LAST_VISITE_DATE","UID_TARGET", @UID) 
 SET @last_station_type = Lookup("ENT.ACTIVITY_LOT_6","LAST_STATION_TYPE","UID_TARGET", @UID) 
]%%
```

**URL example**:

```
href="http://www.exempledomaine.com/fr-BE?CustomerId=%%UID_TARGET%%&refuelDate=%%=v(@last_visite_date)=%%&stationId=%%=v(@last_station_type)=%%&source=mailing"
```

Comment: You are declaring @UID twice, remove the second. On the fr-BE page retrieve the parameters with: SET @  UID = RequestParameter("CustomerID").

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

**AMPSCRIPT CODE:**

```
%%[
var @last_visite_date, @UID, @last_station_type
 SET @UID = [UID_TARGET] 
 SET @lookup = Lookuprows("ENT.ACTIVITY_LOT_6","UID_TARGET", @UID) /*do a lookuprows with UID*/
 If RowCount(@lookup) > 0 Then /*check the row count*/
    set @row = row(@lookup, 1)
    set @last_visite_date = field(@row, "LAST_VISITE_DATE") /*fetch the value from field name*/
    set @last_station_type = field(@row, "LAST_STATION_TYPE") /*fetch the value from field name*/
 endif

SET @url = "http://www.exempledomaine.com/fr-BE"
SET @concatURL = concat("http://www.exempledomaine.com/fr-BE?CustomerId=",@UID,"&refuelDate=",@last_visite_date,"&stationId=",@last_station_type,"&source=mailing")
]%%
```

**URL Exmaple:**

```
href="%%=redirectto(@concatURL)=%%"
```

visit [redirectto](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/redirectto/) and [lookuprows](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuprows/#LookupRows) to know more about this functions.